# Pre- or post-process roxygen snippets

Tags: r, roxygen2

Is there some mechanism by which I can transform the comments that roxygen sees, preferably before it does the roxygen->rd conversion?

For example, suppose I have:

```
#' My function. Does stuff with numbers.
#'
#' This takes an input `x` and does something with it.
#' @param x a number.
myFunction <- function (x) {
}
```

Now, suppose I want to do some conversion of the comment before roxygen parses it, for example replacing all instances of things in backticks with `\code{}`. Ie:

```
preprocess <- function (txt) {
    gsub('`([^ ]+)`', '\\\\code{\\1}', txt)
}
# cat(preprocess('Takes an input `x` and does something with it'.))
# Takes an input \code{x} and does something with it.
```

Can I feed `preprocess` into roxygen somehow so that it will run it on the doclets before (or after would work in this case) roxygen does its document generation?

I don't want to do a permanent find-replace in my `.r` files. As you might guess from my example, I'm aiming towards some rudimentary markdown support in my roxygen comments, and hence wish to keep my `.r` files as-is to preserve readability (and insert the `\code{..}` stuff programmatically).

Should I just write my own version of `roxygenise` that runs `preprocess` on all detected roxygen-style comments in my files, saves them temporarily somewhere, and then runs the *actual* `roxygenise` on those?

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but AFAIK you can write your own roclets and specify these in your roxygen call, i.e. you specify your new `roclet` in the argument `roxygenize(..., roclet=mc_roclet)`

Comment: I'd recommend building on top of https://github.com/hadley/roxygen3, and looking at the internals of the markdown package to do this properly. I would be happy to accept a patch.

Comment: @hadley cheers, I've already checked out a copy roxygen3, just wanted to see if anyone had a hacked-together solution before I started digging around. If I manage to code up something that works I'll submit a patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this a couple of years later, it looks like Roxygen has a function `register.preref.parsers` that one can use to inject their own parsers into roxygen.
One such use of this is the promising [maxygen package](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/maxygen) (markdown + roxygen = maxygen), which a very neat implementation of markdown processing of roxygen comments (albeit only to the CommonMark spec), and you can see how it is used in that package's [macument function](https://github.com/gaborcsardi/maxygen/blob/master/R/package.R). I eagerly await "pandoc + roxygen = pandoxygen"... :)